# recvfrom contains excess bytes

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

This is a multi-client socket program.

When I am trying to run my program the few last recvfrom() do not return any data. But the recvfrom before that have the excess data. Can someone help me how to fix this.

Client:

```
while (1) {
memset(buff, 0, sizeof(buff));  
recvfrom(sockfd,buff,sizeof(buff),0,(struct sockaddr *)&servaddr,&len);
printf("%s\n", buff);
if (buff[0] == 'U') {
    while(1) {
        printf("Insert your username: ");
        fgets(username,sizeof(username),stdin);
        username[strlen(username) - 1] = '\0';
        printf("Username chosen is %s\n", username);
        // Username Check (Error Check)
        if (strlen(username) < 1 || strlen(username) > 16) {
            printf("Minimum of 1 and maximum of 16.\n");
            continue;
        }
        for (i = 0; i < strlen(username); i++) {
            if (isalnum(username[i]) == 0) {
                printf("Username must contain only alphanumeric characters.\n");
                j = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (j = 0) {
            continue;   
        } else {
            break;
        }       
        }
        sendto(sockfd,username,strlen(username),0,(const struct sockaddr *)&servaddr,len);

        memset(username, 0, sizeof(username));  

    } else {
        break;
    }
}               

printf("Players:\n");

memset(buff, 0, sizeof(buff));  

for (i = 0; i < numplayer; i++) {
    printf("BUFF: %s\n", buff);
    recvfrom(sockfd,buff,sizeof(buff),0,(struct sockaddr *)&servaddr,&len);
    printf("%s\n", buff);

    memset(buff, 0, sizeof(buff));  


}
```

Server:

```
      for (i = 0; i < numplayer; i++) {
    while (1) {
        memset(mesg,0,sizeof(mesg));
        if (recvfrom(connfd[i],mesg,sizeof(mesg),0,(struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr,&len) < 0) {
            perror("Recvfrom");
            exit(-1);
        }
        for (j = 0; j < numplayer; j++) {
            if (strcmp(username[j], mesg) == 0) {
                // Reinitialize buff
                memset(buff, 0, sizeof(buff));  
                check = 1;          
                break;
            }
        }

        if (check == 1) {
            check = 0;
            sprintf(buff, "Username already exist!");
            if ( sendto(connfd[i],buff,strlen(buff),0,(const struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr,len) < 0 ) {
                perror("Sendto");
                exit(-1);
            }
            memset(buff, 0, sizeof(buff));  

            continue;
        } else {
            sprintf(buff, "Valid Username!");
            if ( sendto(connfd[i],buff,strlen(buff),0,(const struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr,len) < 0 ) {
                perror("Sendto");
                exit(-1);
            }
            strcpy(username[i], mesg);
            printf("Username of Player %d is %s.\n" ,i + 1,username[i]);
            break;  
        }
    }
}
    printf("Players:");
for (i = 0; i < numplayer; i++) {
    memset(buff, 0, sizeof(buff));  

    sprintf(buff, "> %s", username[i]);
    printf("%s\n", buff);   

    for (j = 0; j < numplayer; j++) {
        if ( sendto(connfd[j],buff,strlen(buff),0,(const struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr,len) < 0 ) {
            perror("Sendto");
            exit(-1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't seem to have any understanding how recvfrom works.  Go read the documentation and look for examples.  Also, see what EJP said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no 'excess bytes'. recvfrom() returns a length. You are ignoring it. It could also be an EOS (0) or an error indication (-1, see 'errno'). You need to check all those possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

TCP connection may segment the data you send to smaller packets.

If you are receiving data of known size, the receiver have to use a loop to get all the bytes of the payload.

You could find some library to do this job for you if you're new to network programming.

[Boost's asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) is one that I can think of, but its syntax may be a bit difficult.

Comment: Or larger. It may coalesce.

Comment: how can I stop receiving bytes if all I want to receive is just the the bytes send by one use of sendto?

Comment: simply breaking out of the while loop might do

Comment: @Red There is no such thing in TCP as 'just the bytes sent by one use of `sendto()`. It is a bye-stream protocol. No message boundaries.